# How to map Table per Type (TPT) inheritance in Entity designer?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I have created a good amount of tables in my database, here are the problem ones:

```
Table Name -Item
    ItemID - PK (Auto Increment)
    Title        

Table Name -Game
    ItemID - PK
    Console   

Table Name -Film
    ItemID - PK
    Type
```

I have also added an association between the ItemID of Item and Film-Item and Game-Item

The issue is when I place this in Visual Studio and use the Entity Framework it seems to somewhat collapse the classes and totally remove Film and Game... I then cannot use Game or Film as an entity in my ASP code, any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your entity model. Also what association did you create? Association between Film and Game probably isn't what you want. If you want inheritance you need association between item and film and between item and game.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my original post. This is the inheritance I have Item and Film and Item and Game. I have had a look at the Model and it allows me to use something like  Item.Film.Customers (Which is strange)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is how Entity designer behaves. If you model your structure in the database and use *Update model from database* it will indeed be modeled as common associations beacuse EF doesn't know yet that you want to model it as inheritance. You will get this:

[image]

You must manually modify this model to use TPT inheritance. First delete both relations. It will also remove navigation properties and you will get this:

[image]

Use *Inheritance* from toolbox (as described on previous screenshot) and draw a line from `Film` to `Item` and from `Game` to `Item`. Now you need to finish this model. The current model will not validate because `ItemId` is mapped in both parent and child entity. Delete `ItemId` from both `Film` and `Game` entities. You can also make Item entity Abstract and you will get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I followed the steps you gave, however when I add my other tables I recieve the following errors: ---- Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines: An entity from one EntitySet is mapped to a row that is also mapped to an entity from another EntitySet with possibly different key. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two unrelated EntitySets to two overlapping groups of rows

Comment: And what do you see if you follow the error. What entity is mapped on that line?

Comment: One points to a different table I have not currently mentioned (there are many tables)..  but it is a table named Track (Many to 1 to a MusicCD) the second Points to Game and the third points to the assocoiation link between a DVDPlayer and an item (showing Item has many to 0..1) DVDPlayer holds a DVDPlayerID(PK) and a Name. A Movie has a Type(which is the PK of a DVDPlayer). I hope this makes some sense.. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok, at least I now understand backgrounds of your problems. You have relations with sub types and after modeling inheritance these relations don't work. I did this already and I end up with modifying XML directly. Designer was somehow unable to correctly setup relations so I must opened it as XML and manually write mapping. It probably worths separate question.

Comment: Did this ever become another questions?  I am having the same issue, but I don't want to duplicate am existing question.  How would I edit the XML to allow for a relationship between two subclasses (subtype tables) of the same parent class?