# ADO.Net EF, SQL and LINQ ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
ViewData.Model = from m in dataModel.Items
                             where m.Loaned == cust.MembershipID
                                   &&
                                   m.MediaItem1.Type != null

                             select new Temp
                                        {
                                           Rating = m.Library.ItemRating.Rating,
                                           Title = m.MediaItem1.Title
                                         };
```

and

```
public class Temp
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public int Rating { get; set; }
        }
```

I create a view using Temp as being the strong type. This works well and displays all the titles and ratings as it should.

What I want to achieve now is the following: I have another type of Item which I want to query also, the query will look very similar to the one above, it will also return titles and ratings, but it is still classed as a different category of 'item'. How can I implement this so it will send both queries through to the View - if that makes sense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It the different type of `Item` is really different entity set in EF model and it is not inherited from `Item` you can simply use union:

```
ViewData.Model = (from m in dataModel.Items
              where m.Loaned == cust.MembershipID &&
                               m.MediaItem1.Type != null
              select new Temp
                  {
                      Rating = m.Library.ItemRating.Rating,
                      Title = m.MediaItem1.Title
                  })
             .Contact(
              from i in dataModel.DifferentItems
              where ...
              select new Temp
                  {
                      ...
                  });
```

But if you have inheritance modeled in your database ([as requested in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439273/how-to-map-table-per-type-tpt-inheritance-in-entity-designer)) you can still query `Item` and you will get information about all derived entities.

Comment: This works in the respect that I can get all the items now in one Viewdata, however I cannot tell the difference from which may be a Movie for example, or which is a Game (Instead I have a list of titles and ratings) how could I make the two different types identifiable? Thanks.

Comment: In such case you must add specil property to Temp and fill it based on type of loaded entity.