# Entity Framework with Include / Joining Issues

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-4

I've implemented an Table Inheritance functionality demonstrated at http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server.

All the foreign keys and constraints are in place.

Now I am using Entity Framework to pull back my People, Students, Teachers, and Parents where the model looks something like the following (without all the EF specific attributes etc).

```
public partial class People : EntityObject
{
  public guid PeopleID { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }  /Added for an example query
  public PeopleParent Parent { get; set; }
  public PeopleStudent Student { get; set; }
  public PeopleTeacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to get all People regardless of type, who are 25 years old, no more than 100 records, and I want to include all the referenced data.  I create my EF Query like:

```
IQueryable<People> query = Entities.People.Include("PeopleParent")
                                           .Include("PeopleStudent")
                                           .Include("PeopleTeacher");

query.Where(x => x.Age == 25)
     .Take(100);

IEnumerable<People> results = query.ToList();
```

Seems simple enough, but whatever table/entityset I've set to include first creates an `INNER JOIN` instead of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which is not producing the right results.

Generated TSQL (incorrect for my needs):

```
SELECT 
  [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1],
  <A bunch of Limit1 Columns>
FROM (
  SELECT TOP (100) 
    [Extent1].[PeopleID] AS [PeopleID],
    <A bunch of Extent1 Columns>
    [Extent2].[PeopleID] AS [PeopleID1], 
    <A bunch of Extent2 Columns>
    [Extent3].[PeopleID] AS [PeopleID2], 
    <A bunch of Extent3 Columns>
    [Extent4].[PeopleID] AS [PeopleID3], 
    <A bunch of Extent4 Columns>
    1 AS [C1]
  FROM [rets].[People] AS [Extent1]
  INNER JOIN [rets].[PeopleParent] AS [Extent2] 
    ON [Extent1].[PeopleID] = [Extent2].[PeopleID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [rets].[PeopleStudent] AS [Extent3] 
    ON [Extent1].[PeopleID] = [Extent3].[PeopleID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [rets].[PeopleTeacher] AS [Extent4] 
    ON [Extent1].[PeopleID] = [Extent4].[PeopleID]
) AS [Limit1]
```

Why is the first Include used as an `INNER JOIN`, and is there a soluion to my problem?

** UPDATE 1**

Assuming I use Ladislav Mrnka's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502748/209259), there are two additional requirements due to the significant change in Linq and Lambda querying.

Question: How do I search for specific People which have specific properties?

(All Students with a Grade of "A")

Answer:

```
context.People.OfType<Student>().Where(s => s.Grade == "A");
```

Question: How do I search for any People that have a specific property?

(All Students or Teachers who's PrimaryFocus = "Math")

Answer:

```
List<People> result = new List<People>();
result.AddRange(context.People.OfType<Student>()
                              .Where(x => x.PrimaryFocus == "Math")
                              .ToList());
result.AddRange(context.People.OfType<Teacher>()
                              .Where(x => x.PrimaryFocus == "Math")
                              .ToList());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious solution for you should be using native EF support for inheritance. In your case [TPT inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439273/how-to-map-table-per-type-tpt-inheritance-in-entity-designer/5443033#5443033). Once you have inheritance you will simply call:

```
IEnumerable<People> results = Entities.People
                                      .Where(x => x.Age == 25)
                                      .Take(100)
                                      .ToList();
```

And it will return you instances of `Student`, `Teachers`, `Parents` etc.

In your solution the only advice is check that the relation is optional (1 - 0..1) - . If it is required it will use `INNER JOIN`. If it is optional and it still uses `INNER JOIN` it can be some bug or other problem in your model.

Comment: I haven't been using the inheritence support in EF.  If I choose to go down this "rabbit hole" to use inheritence, how does it affect searching if I look for `.Where(x => x.Grade == "A")`, when Parents and Teachers don't have a `Grade` property (only students)?

Comment: You cannot search for `People` but for `Students`: `context.People.OfType<Student>().Where(s => s.Grade == "A")`. Inheritance is tricky and it has significant performance costs (this will improve in .NET 4.5) but it's best solution for your database.

Comment: The second question probably doesn't have easy answer. You will have to query students and teachers separately unless the shared property is in `Person` class. You can try some tricks with `Union` of two queries but there will be a problem with casting because union of `Student` and `Teacher` query will not work (they are of different type). EF is about thinking in object oriented queries so not every relational query can be directly translated.

Comment: Since I am returning `IENumerable<People>` I should be able to do two seperate querys and combine the two query results into the single result.

Comment: It will work in Linq-to-objects where implicit cast to People works but probably not in Linq-to-entities where unioned sets must have same columns. So you must execute those queries separately and union them to single `IEnumerable` once returned from the database.