# Inheritance - insert records just on the specialized table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

My base table already has some register ID = 5.
How can I add the same id on the specialized table?

Example:

```
BaseTable
ID INT
Name Varchar(100)

DerivedTable
ID INT
Test BIT
```

I insert some values on the base table

```
Context.BaseTable.Add(new BaseTable(){ Name = '123' });
Context.SaveChanges();
```

The identity is 5

Now I want to add the specialized values

```
Context.DerivedTable.Add(new DerivedTable(){ ID = 5, Test = 1 });
Context.SaveChanges();
```

It didn't work, linqpad is showing to me that sql is trying to create a new BaseTable register.

Is that any way to work around this?

Tks

Comment: Did you map these as 'Table per Type`?

Comment: @Eranga I mapped as inherited table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have it mapped as inheritance ([EDMX TPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439273/how-to-map-table-per-type-tpt-inheritance-in-entity-designer/5443033#5443033), [Code first TPT](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)) you must not insert into base table separately (it should most probably be abstract class in your model). You must only insert to derived table and EF will handle insertion to both mapped tables:

```
Context.DerivedTable.Add(new DerivedTable(){ Name = "123", Test = 1 });
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't want to EF insert on the base table, just on derived

Comment: In such case you cannot use inheritance and you must instead model your classes with normal one-to-one relation.

Comment: I can't change the structure....My workaround was create a Store Procedure and exec through EF. Tks Ladislav

Comment: Is there now a solution to this problem?

Comment: You cannot change the type of an entity with EF once you have inserted it. You must either create a stored procedure for this, or insert it as the correct type in the first place.
If you are using inheritance then you must have a record in both base and derived table for each derived entry.