# EF inheritance and primary keys

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-5

I'm not sure whether this is possible in EF, but I am creating a bunch of classes and am trying to get EF to create the tables for me.

Now EF creates my tables fine, except for a minor issue. It created the tables as:

> Person
>   - PersonId (PK)
>
> Foo
>   - PersonId (PK)
>   - FooId (INT)
>
> Poo
>   - PersonId (PK)
>   - PooId (INT)

Ideally, I want the PersonId in tables Foo and Poo to be a foreign key not as the primary key. Is this possible? Tried using the ModelBuilder to do this via:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasKey(x => x.FooId).ToTable("Foo");

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; private set; }
}

public class Foo : Person
{
    public int FooId { get; private set; }
}

public class Poo : Person
{
    public int PooId { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have implemented inheritance follows the table per type approach where the PK of the base class is the PK of derived classes ***and also*** a FK back to the base class.

You want `PersonId in tables Foo and Poo to be a foreign key not as the primary key`, so by changing your configuration to from

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasKey(x => x.FooId).ToTable("Foo");
```

to

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable("Foo");
```

your database should look like this:

> > Person - PersonId (PK)
> >
> > Foo - PersonId (PK, FK)
> >
> > Poo - PersonId (PK, FK)

[More reading on table per type inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible then to have PersonId to being the FK only and to have FooId in the Foo table to be a PK?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But in this case you should create database by your hand and use code first only to map entities to existing database.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure if what you wanted to do can be done using code first, and @KirillBestemyanov's answer confirms that. Look at this link where Ladislav explains how to map TPT using the designer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439273/how-to-map-table-per-type-tpt-inheritance-in-entity-designer/5443033#5443033

Comment: Thank you. I am installing SP1 and checking the modelling tool that is available.